# How can I record tty1 as a full video capture including xorg?

Tags: xorg, tty, desktop-recording

I built a minimal Ubuntu and I want to show off that it only contains xorg for graphics programs, no DE or WM. But I can't find a way to capture tty1 in a satisfactory way unless I buy a capture card I'll probably never use again.

I would love to be able to show off launching programs with `xinit /path/to/program $* -- :1` and show the program starting up using something like *RecordMyDesktop*, but unfortunately that requires xorg to have already have been started. I looked at other programs like *screen*, but it only records the text in the tty console. Is there maybe a way to mirror tty1 to a graphical program in tty7 and record it that way?

Comment: Install your system in a virtualbox or vmware session. That's how most make images and videos of boot sessions.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason when I startx and firefox It run worse then my xubuntu virtual machine (by that I mean I can see the vertical scan line while it's running at 2 fps). I even made sure the guest additions were installed and it didn't make a difference.  Which is odd, because natively it runs smoother then using a DE and/or WM on computer.